# How to differentiate two tables

Tags: sql, android, sqlite

I have two tables and I want to get all records from one table that are different from the records in second table.

Eg.: if we have four records in the first table like A,B,C,D and three records in the second table thats A,B,C then the answer of query should be D.

I have tried "EXCEPT" operator but it doesn't work fine. Kindly help me in writing correct query for the given problem.

Comment: Why is this tagged with android?

Comment: @aioobe: Probably because the OP is trying to do this in an Android app. Noting that could be important if the syntax of the query is slightly different; e.g. Android provides some "managed query" methods and giving the specific command for them would be more useful than a generic SQL statement.

Answer (score 7):

How about:

```
select * from TABLE_A where (COL,COL2,..) not in (select COL1,COL2,.. from TABLE_B) 
union all 
select * from TABLE_B where (COL1,COL2,..) not in (select COL1,COL2,.. from TABLE_A);
```

Answer (score 3):

If the first table is called TABLE_A, and the second table is called TABLE_B, in order to enhance the differences you can use the MINUS operand, both sides.  This means:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_B
MINUS
SELECT * FROM TABLE_A;
```

The previous statement shows the records present in TABLE_B, but not present in TABLE_A.

Of course, you have to use the MINUS in the other side:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_A
MINUS
SELECT * FROM TABLE_B;
```

The previous statement shows the records present in TABLE_A, but not present in TABLE_B.

If you don't want to use MINUS, you can create two Oracle VIEWS with the previous statements.

Comment: Probably he can't use Oracle views, given that he has tagged the question 'android' and 'sqlite'.  But for the more general problem you are certainly right.

Comment: minus doesnt present in SQLite.I want to get this done in android.

Comment: @Nemat I tested the query using EXCEPT instead of MINUS on SQLite and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

how about this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Field1
FROM Table1 
WHERE Field1 Not IN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT Field1 FROM Table2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the EXCEPT, it works as follows :

Table Test1 : A, B, C
Table Test2 : A, B, C, D

```sql
SELECT * FROM test1
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM Test2;
```

Will return you the records which are there in **test1** but not in **test2**. Result will be null.

```sql
SELECT * FROM test2
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM Test1;
```

Will return you the records which are present in **test2** but not in **test1**. Result for this query will give you "D".

Comment: I have used this query but it doesn't give me the required answer.
Here is my code:

Cursor c=db.rawQuery("select * from "+table1+ 
          " EXCEPT "+
          "select * from "+table2 
                 ,null)

Actually both of my tables have similar records.It works fine for the first time only i.e. it gives 0 records.After that it starts giving all the records of the first table we can say as we have similar records in both tables.

Where is the error I dont understand.

Comment: Are there same attributes in both the tables i.e table1 and table2 ?

Comment: If you have different attributes then you can't use "select *", you need to use the similar attributes from both the tables.

Comment: Doesn't what I wrote in my answer work?
I tried it few times with different tables, removing all records with the same ID, and it worked every time.
You should try it.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_B
MINUS
SELECT * FROM TABLE_A;
```

This may not work in sqlite, but the following does

```
SELECT DISTINCT Field1
FROM Table1 
WHERE Field1 Not IN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT Field1 FROM Table2);
```