# Comparing two tables in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables and want to compare rows on sqlite like this

```
table1           table2
field1           field1

a                   a
b                   d
c                   f
d                   g
e
f
g
h
i
```

and I want to produce result like this

```
result_table
field1

b
c
e
h
i
```

How is the syntax in sqlite?
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to differentiate two tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819151/how-to-differentiate-two-tables)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT Field1
FROM Table1 
WHERE Field1 Not IN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT Field1 FROM Table2)
```

Comment: this does not identify records in table2 that are not in table1

Answer (score 9):

```
SELECT columns1 FROM table1 EXCEPT SELECT columns2 FROM table2;
```

The SQLite EXCEPT clause returns all rows from the left SELECT statement that are not in the result of the second SELECT statement. The number of columns selected must be the same in both SELECT statements.

This works fine for small to medium size tables. Avoid for tables with millions of lines.

See [Compound Select Statements](https://www.sqlite.org/syntax/compound-select-stmt.html) and the documentation of the SQLite [SELECT](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html) statement.

Comment: Adding some explanation to your code will help to make it a better answer.